# Combinatorial proofs by induction

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I'm having some difficulties with these kind of problems in linear algebra. I'm translating them, so there may be some mistakes.

**Problem 1** 
Let X be a set with $n$ elements and $1 \leq m\leq n$. Prove by induction:
a) The number of injective functions from $\{1,2,...m\}$ to $X$ is $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$
b) The number of bijective functions from $\{1,2,...n\}$ to $X$ or from X to $X$ is $n!$

I don't really understand the meaning of "the injective functions ..." I'm only in my first year of maths course, I know what an injective function is, but I don't understand its relationship with this.

**Problem 2**
Let $X$ be a set with n elements and $0\leq m \leq n$. Prove the number of subsets with m elements is $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!\cdot m!}$ ( there must be two possible proofs,according to the teacher, one by induction and another one)

Thank you, and forgive the mistakes: I don't speak English very well and I'm just beginning with maths.

Comment: Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ for example and let $m=2$.  We are tasked with counting the number of possible injective functions from $\{1,2\}$ to $X$.  One such function is $f(1)=a,f(2)=b$.  Another is $f(1)=a,f(2)=c$.  A third possibility is $f(1)=b,f(2)=a$ and so on...  We could write out the entire list of possible functions by brute force but there is no reason to since we can figure it out analytically.  Your task is to find an analytical approach to the problem and discover why there must be $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ possible injective functions from $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ to $X$.

Comment: For the first, consider reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#Injective_functions_from_N_to_X).  For the second, consider reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  In either case, the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) will be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've helped me a lot . I think I finally understand them now